# WPF Localized TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, localization, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Here's the thing:

I have a simple WPF Windows application, in which I've included a `TreeView`, which is being constructed with the help of `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and fed with some hierarchical data.

The hierarchical data structure is made of FakeRec class, which contains child items in a `List<FakeRec>`. Each item contains a Title string property.
So in my XAML, I have:

```
...
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DataType="{x:Type local:FakeRec}">
...
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
...
```

This works fine, and in the generated `TreeView` I see the title of each node.

Now I want to make this whole tree localizable.
I have my resources in FakeDirResources.Resx (in a separate assembly, but that does not matter).
If I do this:

```
...
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DataType="{x:Type local:FakeRec}">
...
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Title, Source={StaticResource FakeDirResources}}"/>
...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
...
```

My tree is blank (obviously, because in my `FakeDirResources.resx` file I don't have a resource with key `Title`, but I need to use the `Title` of the other binding, resolve it through the resources, and then somehow bind the result to the tree.

Note that if i just place a `TextBlock` on the window, without relation to the tree or to the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, I can bind it without problem to the resources, like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=games, Source={StaticResource FakeDirResources}}"/>;
```

This works great, fetching the string, and if I change the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and refresh my provider, this string gets changed to to the new language.

The question is how do I combine the two? What am I missing?
I guess there has to be some trick (and with my short experience with WPF it's probably not a straight-forward trick).

Cheers!

Alon.

Comment: Am I to understand that `Title` contains the key into the `FakeDirResources`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially you could work through this with an `IValueConverter`:

```
public class KeyResourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var key = System.Convert.ToString(value);
        var lookup = parameter as ResourceManager;

        return lookup.GetString(key, culture);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Used like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title,
                          Converter={StaticResource keyResource}
                          ConverterParameter={x:Static local:FakeDirResources.ResourceManager}}"
           />
```